# Move data from 4 shard, replicated mongodb cluster to a single server without downtime

Tags: mongodb, migration

I need to move sharded data from four replica sets to a single remote machine without downtime. Can you describe the process step by step?

Comment: Just running rs.initialize() will disconnect all users and cause downtime.  What do you mean by 'no downtime' per say?

Comment: can't we just add a single machine with 4 mongod instances, add each instance to one of replica sets, force them to became masters and then start to remove shards, that will automatically migrate data to remaining shards, and when only one shard is left, we can remove the old master?

Comment: Ok, so you're not doing any MongoDB upgrades, correct?  Just migrating data to a new cluster and no other changes?

Comment: yes the same cluster should be up all the tame and move to a single data server in remote location.

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario there is a good discussion on this already on the Mongo Jira server on unsharding a database:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9845

Test and stage these steps using your real data in a non prod environment repeatedly until you are confident and find one that works:

```
database = 'test'
collection = database + '.fs.chunks'

sh.stopBalancer()
use config
primary = db.databases.findOne({_id: database}).primary

// move all chunks to primary
db.chunks.find({ns: collection, shard: {$ne: primary}}).forEach(function(chunk){
    print('moving chunk from', chunk.shard, 'to', primary, '::', tojson(chunk.min), '-->', tojson(chunk.max));
    sh.moveChunk(collection, chunk.min, primary);
});

// unshard
db.collections.remove({ "_id" : "test.fs.chunks" })
db.chunks.remove({ ns : collection })

// flush all mongos, is this neccessary?!
use admin
db.runCommand({ flushRouterConfig: 1 })
```

Note now you have unsharded your data.  If you don't want to just directly unshard it before sending it over to the new cluster, then setup the new cluster sharded, and after it's synched then unshard it.